# How to Replace the http:// from the current page url of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

Hi I tried to  Replace the `http:// or https://` from the current url of wordpress site. I tried to replace the `http:// by str_replace`. I fetch the current url by `the_permalink();`

```
<?php echo str_replace(array('http://','https://'),'',the_permalink());?>
```

that above code is not working but when i trying to get the url from admin input similar to this

```
<?php echo str_replace(array('http://','https://'),'',get_option('URL'));?>
```

That Get Option is working Perfect but for the permalink is not working why any suggestion would be great.

Thanks,
vicky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I Get the suggestion tried by googling here is the one that i tried.

```
 the_permalink() function will print the output before you can perform anything so try uses get_permalink() function instead.
```

I use the get_permalink(); instead of the_permalink and it works perfect thanks. I Tried to close this question. But this information that i tried is helpful for someone.

```
<?php echo str_replace(array('http://','https://'),'',get_permalink());?>
```

Thanks,
vicky

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function current_url(){        
                        return document.URL;
                    }


 var current_url=window.parent.current_url();   // current_url contains the value of the current URL             
                </script>
```

This will return you the current page URL..

Comment: Thanks I finally Figure out the problem.that was i posted below. Thanks for spends ur valuable time. :)

Comment: I get the current page url perfect. But My Question is to replace the http:// from the current page url.

Comment: Glad you are giving the suggestion to get the current page url through javascript

Comment: once you have the complete URL you can play with it as there are number of functions in php and jquery for string replace

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax isn't right.

If you want links to be http:// on an https:// site use `<a href="<?php echo str_replace('https://','http://',get_permalink());?>">`;

Otherwise use `<a href="<?php echo str_replace('http://','https://',get_permalink());?>">`